# Airflow ECS-Operator not fetching CloudWatch Logs

Tags: airflow, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Airflow's EcsOperator, ECS tasks writing to Cloudwatch.
Sometimes Airflow log fetcher collects logs from CloudWatch and sometimes does not.
On the CloudWatch console, I always see the logs.
On tasks that take a long time, I usually see the log or at least part of it.
Someone had the same issue with ECSOperator?

Answer (score 1):

First `ECSOperator` is deprecated and removed in provider version 5.0.0
You should switch to `EcsRunTaskOperator`.

In `EcsRunTaskOperator` there is [`awslogs_fetch_interval`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2a34dc9e8470285b0ed2db71109ef4265e29688b/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs.py#L367) which control over the interval to fetch logs from Ecs. The default is 30 seconds. If you wish for more frequent polls then set the parameter value accordingly.

You didn't mention what provider version you are on but this part of the code was refactored in version 5.0.0 ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25413)) so upgrading the Amazon provider might also resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi @Elad Kalif and thanks for your response.
The provider version I'm using is 6.0.0 and I switched the operator now ECSOperator => EcsRunTaskOperator.
If I understand correctly by default fetch_interval is 30 seconds and the worker will fetch the log anyway when the task is complete/fails.

I've noticed delays in CW logs (sometimes more than two minutes) and AWS support confirms that CloudWatch is not working in real-time and writing in batches.
When there are delays in CloudWatch, we will lose logs and XCOM.
Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: @alon_r I think what you really need is operator extra link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/define_extra_link.html#define-an-operator-extra-link thus you can reach from task instance to Ecs log without dumping it to Airflow task logs. You can probably implement your own custom operator with it.